# 'Event loop' to detect crontab update?

Tags: linux, cron

Where I work we have a couple different crontabs (spread across users and servers) that are responsible for the scheduled jobs our ETL pipeline. There are a lot of moving parts, and I'd like to display all the crontabs in one place in a tabular fashion on a dashboard.  The first step for this would involve running script that parses each of these crontabs.

There are several approaches to this I have in mind

1. run this script at some hourly interval
2. run this script only upon a get request to the dashboard. This would be more accurate than the above, and since this dashboard wouldn't get that much traffic this would be ok, but...

I'd rather the script run only if a crontab is updated.  Is it possible to monitor if a crontab gets updated?  (Is there such a concept as an 'event loop' in unix like systems to detect file changes like this?)  Or are one of the two approaches I listed ok as is?

Comment: Yes, the `iwatch` system. Read `man iwatch`, see `http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/`.

Comment: I'm guessing I'd use this to monitor the `/var/spool/cron` for a user, correct?

Comment: You can generate stats per machine even on event: like ssh from collector periodically, store parseable data files on collector, analyze and display on demand. If you are feeling fancy you can use some inotify watcher which there are plenty of on each host and make them push updates to collector.

Comment: You can use `inotifywatch` in a `while` loop to handle events for `/var/spool/cron` `/var/spool/cron/*` `/etc/crontab` (`root`'s `crontab`). NB: If you're processing `inotifywatch` through `grep`, be sure to use `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option, otherwise the first event won't be output until `grep` has a bufferfull.